# unique_ptr's assignment operator copies a deleter stored by a reference. Is it a feature or a bug?

Tags: c++, c++11, smart-pointers, unique-ptr

Imaging the case when you have an `unique_ptr` with a custom deleter stored by a reference:

```
struct CountingDeleter
{
    void operator()(std::string *p) {
        ++cntr_;
        delete p;
    }

    unsigned long cntr_ = 0;
};

int main()
{
    CountingDeleter d1{}, d2{};

    {
        std::unique_ptr<std::string, CountingDeleter&>
            p1(new std::string{"first"} , d1),
            p2(new std::string{"second"}, d2);

        p1 = std::move(p2); // does d1 = d2 under cover
    }

    std::cout << "d1 " << d1.cntr_ << "\n"; // output: d1 1
    std::cout << "d2 " << d2.cntr_ << "\n"; // output: d2 0
}
```

It was a surprise for me that the assignment in the code above has a side-effect of copying `d2` into `d1`. I've double check it and found that this behavior is as described in the standard in [[unique.ptr.single.asgn]](http://eel.is/c++draft/unique.ptr.single.asgn):

> (1) - Requires: If `D` is not a reference type, `D` shall satisfy the requirements of `MoveAssignable` and assignment of the deleter from an rvalue of type `D` shall not throw an exception.
>   Otherwise, `D` is a reference type; `remove_reference_t<D>` shall satisfy the `CopyAssignable` requirements and assignment of the deleter from an lvalue of type `D` shall not throw an exception.
>
> (2) - Effects: Transfers ownership from `u` to `*this` as if by calling `reset(u.release())` followed by `get_deleter() = std::forward<D>(u.get_deleter())`.

To get the behavior that I expected (a shallow copy of the deleter reference) I had to wrap the deleter reference into `std::reference_wrapper`:

```
std::unique_ptr<std::string, std::reference_wrapper<CountingDeleter>>
    p1(new std::string{"first"} , d1),
    p2(new std::string{"second"}, d2);

p1 = std::move(p2); // p1 now stores reference to d2 => no side effects!
```

For me the current handling of a deleter reference in the unique ptr is counter-intuitive and even error-prone:

1. When you store a deleter by a reference rather than by value this mostly because you want the shared deleter with some important unique state. So you don't expect the shared deleter is overwritten and its state is lost after a unique ptr assignment.
2. It's expected that assignment of a unique_ptr is extremely chip, especially if the deleter is a reference. But instead of this, you get copying of the deleter what can be (unexpectedly) expensive.
3. After the assignment, the pointer become bound to original deleter's copy, rather than to the original deleter itself. This might lead to some unexpected side-effects if the deleter's identity is important.
4. Also, current behavior prevents from using a const reference to a deleter because you just can't copy into a const object.

IMO it would be better to forbid a deleters of reference types and accept only a movable value types.

So my question is the following (it looks like two questions in one, sorry):

- Is there any reason why the standard `unique_ptr` behaves like this?
- Does anybody have a good example where it's useful to have a reference type deleter in `unique_ptr` rather than a non-reference one (i.e. a value type)?

Comment: This is how references work - "assigning" a value to a reference assigns a value to the referenced object; the reference and the object are the same thing. You can't replace a reference to one object with a reference to a different object, you can only replace the value of one object with a (copy of) the value of a different object.

Comment: I know how reference assignment works. I'm asking why the standard didn't make unique_ptr a bit more smart in case of storing a deleter reference. The current behavior looks useless unless std::reference_wrapper is used.

Comment: The current behaviour is useless _for what you're trying to do_ but that doesn't mean it's useless. It means you're not using it as it's meant to be used.

Comment: Jonathan, could you give me an example when the standard behavior is useful?

Comment: I don't know why you're using references, but the point of storing a deleter by reference is to avoid copying it, because it's heavyweight, or not copyable. If you want to use a feature that is intended to avoid copying the deleter, but then want to modify (i.e. copy) it then you need to think about what that will mean and define assignment for your type correctly.

Comment: It's not about avoiding a copy because a deleter is heavy or not copyable. It's about sharing a deleter with unique identity between multiple unique pointers.

Comment: My answer shows a simpler way to do that without references, where the identity of the counter is what matters, not the deleters. i.e. put the state outside the deleter.

Comment: To get this without reference I already use a reference_wrapper. Please read my question: I an not looking for a workaround, I'm trying to understand the reason for the current design of unique_ptr. At the moment I don't see any point why a deleter reference is allowed at all.

Comment: Why shouldn't deleter reference be allowed? What would be the point of disallowing it?

Comment: It will remove a confusion in unique_ptr behavior. It would be OK to have it if there is a use case for it, but so far, no one was mentioned, thus I see only a cons form this feature.

Comment: I guess I don't see that the behavior is confusing, it's pretty much what you should expect if you think about it. Core language features typically don't have an explicit, dedicated use that justifies each and every one of them. Instead, sometimes features that were useful in C++98 are hardly used in C++11, or features that were rarely used now may be much more useful in concert with future additions. If you think its a bug you probably should take the stance that it breaks something rather than try to put the onus on everyone else to illustrate the utility of the normal behavior.

Comment: Or explain why it would make more sense the other (another?) way? I must admit it's not entirely clear to me what change you would have in mind. Keep in mind also that if unique_ptr with reference deleter would just be disabled using sfinae or something, just because you think its ugly, well c++11 has been out there for 5 years now, so surely there are some people whose programs would be broken by this and wouldn't appreciate being forced to rewrite them.

Comment: @Chris, I'm trying to understand why it was decided that the move-assignment operator copies the referenced deleter. So far I don't see any point for this neither a real use case. By default, the move/copy assignment operator is not generated if class has a reference member. And that's for purpose.

Answer (score 13):

This is a feature.

If you have stateful deleters presumably the state is important, and is associated with the pointer that it will be used to delete. That means the deleter state should be transferred when ownership of the pointer transfers.

But if you store a deleter by reference it means you care about the identity of the deleter, not just its value (i.e. it's state), and updating the `unique_ptr` should not re-bind the reference to a different object.

So if you don't want this, why are you even storing a deleter by reference?

What does a shallow copy of a reference even *mean*? There's no such thing in C++. If you don't want reference semantics, don't use references.

If you really want to do this, then the solution is simple: define assignment for your deleter to not change the counter:

```
CountingDeleter&
operator=(const CountingDeleter&) noexcept
{ return *this; }
```

Or since what you really seem to care about is the counter, not the deleter, keep the counter outside the deleter and don't use reference deleters:

```
struct CountingDeleter
{
    void operator()(std::string *p) {
        ++*cntr_;
        delete p;
    }

    unsigned long* cntr_;
};

unsigned long c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
CountingDeleter d1{&c1}, d2{&c2};

{
    std::unique_ptr<std::string, CountingDeleter>
        p1(new std::string{"first"} , d1),
        p2(new std::string{"second"}, d2);
```

Comment: Jonathan, by shallow copy of a reference I meant behavior of std::reference_wrapper. This is in fact just a non-null pointer with syntax sugar around.

Comment: Right, that's pointer semantics. Why are you surprised that a reference behaves like a reference not like a pointer? `reference_wrapper` is the oddity, not the reference.

Comment: I just trying to find a use-case for current behavior and the reason why unique_ptr is not using a reference_wrapper internally what IMO will make it just more convenient :)

Comment: More convenient _if you don't want your reference to act like a reference_.

Comment: Please give an example where the current handling of a deleter reference is useful. Your answer has a lot of upvotes but it has no actual answer to my questions.

Comment: It behaves the way it does _because that's how references behave_. Use a reference to avoid copying heavy objects, but if you do that, it behaves like a reference.

Comment: In fact, rather than avoid a copy it introduces it. :)

Comment: "What does a shallow copy of a reference even mean? There's no such thing in C++. If you don't want reference semantics, don't use references." I mean I guess what OP wants is that, a new reference is initialized, using the value bound from the old reference. @oliora, Effectively what you are asking is that when you copy assign `unique_ptr`, the old deleter is *destroyed* and a new one is *copy constructed* or something like this. But of course that's now how assignment operators work in C++, that's why this isn't a bug. Making a custom type indeed seems like a good approach for you.

Comment: Whether or not it's "useful" that it works this way, it would be very confusing if it didn't.

Comment: If it's not useful it can be disabled. Value-only semantics works just fine for std::bind, std::shared_ptr's deleter and for allocators.

Answer (score 2):

Having reference data members often leads to surprising results because assigning to a reference has non-value semantics because a reference cannot be re-assigned to refer to another object. Basically, reference data members break your assignment operator semantics.

Using pointer members instead fixes that. Alternatively, use `std::reference_wrapper<>` and `std::ref()`.

---

> Why does it perform a deep copy of a deleter stored by a reference rather than just a shallow copy?

It performs member-wise copy. If the value being copied is a pointer, that happens to be a shallow copy.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't use a pointer to a "shared deleter" without wrapping it into a lambda or some other by-value wrapper around the pointer.

The standard clearly distinguish cases when the deleter is a reference type and when it is not a reference type. I'm wondering, why, having such a clear distinguish, they didn't make a reference case more easy to use or just forbid it.

Comment: Yep, std::reference_wrapper helps. I mentioned it above. I mean, I know the workaround and asking more about why the standard put it like it is now, so people has to use workaround for a quite common use case...

Btw, nice to talk to you again. Your const_string library is great!

Answer (score 0):

A reference can't be reseated after initialization. It acts in all ways as the object it refers to. And that includes assignment.

Because the reference acts as the object that it refers to, the copying of the referent is what you'd get in an ordinary class with an assignment operator implemented as a sequence of per-member assignments.

Comment: Yes. But my question is about different thing. It's like a class with a reference member and for such a class copy/move assignment is deleted. Because assigning to a reference member is not what most users would expect and resetting of a reference is not possible. Thus there is only one option is to delete the assignment.

Comment: It's unclear to me *why* `unique_ptr` supports a reference as deleter type. But given that it does, and that it's a no overhead class, the copy referent behavior isn't unreasonable. Because the reference acts as the object that it refers to, it's what you'd get in an ordinary class with an assignment operator implemented as a sequence of per-member assignments. [I added that last sentence to the answer, explicitly drawing the conclusion.]