# unique_ptr and callable object to free it's object

Tags: c++11

Here I have simple program:

```
struct A{
    int t=0;

    operator() (int *p) {cout << "operator() (int *p)\n";delete p;};

    ~A() {cout << "~A\n";};
};

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    {
        unique_ptr<int, A> u(new int[9]{0});
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The program creates an unique_ptr on array of int. And use callable object A to destroy pointer. All is simple. But when I run the program the output is:

```
~A
operator() (int *p)
~A
```

I don't understand why destructor calling two time. If there is some idea?

Comment: Probably unrelated, but still: you use `new[]` for allocation, but `delete` instead of `delete[]` for deallocation, which invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The unique_ptr takes a copy of the deleter object by feature to preserve the state, for more information.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35318283/4669663

Here is the code I've tried to confirm that the copy constructor is invoked for deleter when unique_ptr is created,

http://cpp.sh/7yqw2

Answer (score 0):

On my Computer with `g++ (GCC) 7.1.1 20170516` I get the output

```
$ ./test2
operator() (int *p)
~A
```

with your programm.

It will depend on your compiler and standard library implementation. Probably `std::unique_ptr` makes an additional copy of an object of type `A` and the source is then probably destroyed.

Comment: I use MinGW on windows.

Comment: I'm sure putting a breakpoint on the destructor will provide an answer.  At a rough guess, the implementation internally makes a function call passing an instance of A.  Both passing by-value and moving the instance will result in two copies and thus two destructions.

Answer (score 0):

In my search, I found that it's better to use default_delete<>()

```
shared_ptr<int> u(new int[9], default_delete<int[]>());
```